# How to enable PHP cookies?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am facing a problem recently with PHP Sessions, on every browser refresh the sessions are getting lost.

I saw that the PHPSESSID is not being read in the cookies.

Then i tried this piece of code.

```
            echo (isset($_COOKIE['foo']) && $_COOKIE['foo']=='bar') ? 'enabled' : 'disabled';
```

And it seems that PHP cookies are disabled.

My question is this: How can i enable the PHP cookies? What is causing this problem?

Is it a server configuration?

Thank you in advance. Hope to read an explanation from someone.

Comment: There's no such thing as *PHP Cookies* - it's all HTTP cookies whether you're setting them from PHP or JavaScript; I assume you *are* actually setting `$_COOKIE['foo']` before that echo and that you're reloading the page (since the cookie won't exist first time around)?

Comment: I used that one too, but also this piece of code     $a = session_id();
session_destroy();

session_start();
$b = session_id();
session_destroy();

if ($a == $b)
    echo"Cookies ON";
else
    echo"Cookies OFF";                                    So the cookies are off, what do you think, what's the reason the cookies went off? I have done through .htaccess a redirection to https, i thought that may be the problem but i removed that part of commands and the problem still persists.

Comment: ^ you realise now that that will **a)** not work and **b)** makes no sense at all? Having `$a = session_id()` **before** `session_start()` will be `null`. Then you're destroying a session you haven't started yet... and so on...

Comment: Oh yeah i realized that, but i am trying with this code to check whether the cookies are enabled or disabled:    echo (isset($_COOKIE['foo']) && $_COOKIE['foo']=='bar') ? 'enabled' : 'disabled';
They are disabled.

Comment: Yes - but you haven't clarified whether you 1) actually set the cookie before that (e.g. with `setcookie()`) and 2) reloaded the page (as the cookie won't be available first time around).

Comment: No, i haven't set the command setcookie() before any other piece of code.

Comment: Well in the case of `echo (isset($_COOKIE['foo']) && $_COOKIE['foo']=='bar')` ... if you've not `setcookie()` before then `$_COOKIE['foo']` won't be set... `$_COOKIE` is just a superglobal array that gives you access to existing cookie data, it won't actually set the cookies.

Comment: I don't really get this man, the point is that it used to work before and now sessions are getting lost on refresh, do i have to call the setcookie() function on top of the php page? And other cookies are being saved it's just that PHPSESSID is not being saved.

Comment: Nah, you don't use `setcookie()` with session cookies; you configure the session cookie through the [ini settings](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) (beginning `session.cookie_*`); `session_start()` then deals with creating the relevant session cookie... and that should be basically it. You would need `setcookie()` with your `$_COOKIE['foo'] ...` test script though.

Comment: Should i set this command on php.ini  session.use_cookies=1?

Comment: Should be set by default, but won't hurt - you can also do it at runtime through `ini_set()`

Comment: ini_set('session.use_cookies','1''), is this right?

Comment: Yeah, any *truthy* value would do it in `ini_set` - e.g. `ini_set("session.use_cookies", true);` Oh, I assume you're calling [session_set_cookie_params()](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) before `session_start()`

Comment: Oh man, sorry for this long discussion, but it is crucial for me to fix this. So i want to put the commands in this order on top of my php file session_set_cookie_params(); 
session_start();
ini_set('session.use_cookies',true); ????

Comment: `ini_set()` -> `session_name()` (if you want) -> `session_set_cookie_params()` -> `session_start()` ... I just dropped it all into a Singleton class ages ago which I keep re-using.

Comment: hmm, i used this exact order but to no result ini_set('session.use_cookies','1');
session_name();
session_set_cookie_params();
session_start();

Comment: You are actually setting the cookie parameters in `session_set_cookie_params()` right? There's a chunk of them: http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: No i am not. I put it in   ini_set('session.use_cookies','1'); as you see the code, o i just call the ini_set() without parameters and put these paremeters instead in session_set_cookie_params('session.use_cookies','1')

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places to do it, either in your php config, or in an htaccess file.

**Config**

find and change this setting in your php.ini file:

```
session.use_cookies=1
```

[heres the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) on this and all the other cookie related switches.

note: if you dont know where youre php.ini file is, from the command line, type `$ php --ini` and itll show you where its located for the cli, the server version will likely be up one level in an apache2/nginx folder.

**htaccess**

check you dont have this line in your .htaccess file.

```
SetEnv session.use_cookies='0';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i just checked the php.ini file and i didn't see anywhere this part of command session.use_cookies=1, i guess i have to add this command?

Comment: its on by default. so Id check the other option in my answer first.

Comment: No, there is no session.use_cookies='0' command in .htaccess file

Comment: And the result of executing this code is: string(1) "1"

Comment: (Apologies, bad copy paste from me previously that led you to checking the wrong parameter.)  How about checking your environment first (before changing your config) to ascertain if this is even the problem? var_dump(ini_get('session.use_cookies'));